Convert INumber<T> in c# to float? .net 7 or newer
Is there a way to convert an integer to a approviate float and back? Some function that gets and returns ints need float during the computation.
Look at this:
void Main()
{
    Interpolation.LinearBetween((0, 5), (10, 3), 7).DumpIt();
    Interpolation.LinearBetween((0.0f, 5), (10, 3), 7).RoundToInt().DumpIt();

}


public static class Interpolation
{
    public static T LinearBetween<T>((T x1, T y1) a, (T x2, T y2) b, T x) where T : INumber<T>
    {
        //f(x) = m*x + n
        //one oft operands needs to be floating point type
        var m = (b.y2 - a.y1) / (b.x2 - a.x1);
        var n = b.y2 - m * b.x2;

        return (x * m + n);
    }

    public static int RoundToInt(this float value)
    {
        return (int)Math.Round(value);
    }

    public static void DumpIt(this object toDump)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(toDump);
    }
}

Doing the whole LinearBetween is not correct.
Edit: Rewitten the question.

Why do you want to convert to float before division? INumber<T> means the type T already implements IDivisionOperators. The methods returns a T, not a float

@PoulBak: Without knowing the context, we can't possibly know whether that's appropriate advice. There are plenty of times where the precision of float is absolutely fine.

This question is similar to: How to convert numbers into generic type?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@PoulBak: That may be your opinion, but it seems irrelevant to the question, and seems to assume that you know more about the OP's domain than they do.

I'm assuming (maybe wrongly you are wanting to convert to float to avoid integral division, but if T is an integral type, you'll have to convert it back to T, so it's not clear what the right answer should be in that case.

Are you sure generic math is the way to go? Instead of the more conventional approach of separate types, i.e. Point vs PointF? I have been somewhat disappointed with generic math, since even something like T Mul2<T>(T value) where T : IMultiplyOperators<T, int, T> => value * 2 does not work with a floating point argument.

What you'd like to do here is, in the context of C#'s generic math, when performing a complex calculation on values of some arbitrary numeric type T, when T also happens to be a generic binary integer, to perform the calculation using floating point precision and only round off at the very end.
This is possible, but awkward.  Here's one possible way:
public static class Interpolation
{
    public static T LinearBetween<T>((T x1, T y1) a, (T x2, T y2) b, T x) where T : INumber<T> =>
        LinearBetween<T, double>(a, b, x); // TODO: decide whether float is precise enough

    public static T LinearBetween<T, TFloat>((T x1, T y1) a, (T x2, T y2) b, T x) 
        where T : INumber<T>, INumberBase<T>
        where TFloat : IFloatingPoint<TFloat>
    {
        if (NumericTypeInformation<T>.IsBinaryInteger)
        {
            // An integer type.  Convert to the preferred float format, perform the calculation, then round at the very end.
            var floatResult =  LinearBetweenUnconverted(
                (TFloat.CreateChecked(a.x1), TFloat.CreateChecked(a.y1)),
                (TFloat.CreateChecked(b.x2), TFloat.CreateChecked(b.y2)),
                TFloat.CreateChecked(x));
            var rounded = TFloat.Round(floatResult, MidpointRounding.ToEven); // TODO: choose your preferred MidpointRounding
            return T.CreateChecked(rounded);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not an integer type.  Perform the calculation directly.
            return LinearBetweenUnconverted(a, b, x);
        }
    }

    static T LinearBetweenUnconverted<T>((T x1, T y1) a, (T x2, T y2) b, T x) where T : INumber<T>
    {
        var m = (b.y2 - a.y1) / (b.x2 - a.x1);
        var n = b.y2 - m * b.x2;

        return (x * m + n);
    }
}

// Generic class to static cache type information about a given numeric type.
public static class NumericTypeInformation<TNumber> where TNumber : INumberBase<TNumber>
{
    readonly static Lazy<bool> isBinaryInteger = new Lazy<bool>(
        () => typeof(TNumber)
              .GetInterfaces()
              .Where(i => i.IsGenericType)
              .Select(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
              .Any(i => i == typeof(IBinaryInteger<>)));

    public static bool IsBinaryInteger => isBinaryInteger.Value;
}

Demo fiddle here.
Key points:

You can use INumberBase<TSelf>.CreateChecked<TOther>(TOther) to create one type of number from another, e.g. to create a float or double from an int or short and vice versa.  This particular method throws in the event of an overflow.  If you don't want that, you could use CreateTruncating() or CreateSaturating()

Once you have converted your arbitrary numbers to some floating type, you can do the calculation in that type, then round off using IFloatingPoint<TSelf>.Round(TSelf, MidpointRounding) , then finally convert back using CreateChecked() in reverse.

I chose to do the intermediate calculations in double rather than float purely due to personal preference.

Checking to see whether whether an arbitrary INumber<T> type implements IBinaryInteger<T> is bizarrely hard!  I thought it would be possible to do something like
static bool IsBinaryInteger<T>() where T : INumber<T> =>
    typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(IBinaryInteger<T>);

But this results in a compilation error

The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'TSelf' in the generic type or method 'IBinaryInteger<TSelf>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.Numerics.IBinaryInteger<T>'.

I think (but am not sure) that the problem is that IBinaryInteger<TSelf> has a constraint where TSelf : IBinaryInteger<TSelf> -- so it may be  impossible to check it a type TSelf implements IBinaryInteger<TSelf> unless it is already constrained to do so!
As an alternative, I had to loop though all the interfaces implemented by T and check whether any are generic interfaces whose open generic type is IBinaryInteger<>.  Since this is likely slow, I cached the result statically.



Note -- tested on .NET 8 not .NET 7.
